# How pagination works in api system (frontend is laravel and backend is laravel from api )?

Tags: php, laravel, api, pagination, frontend

*I have a project for a list branch , the frontend is created using laravel and the backend is created also using laravel, This is an API system. I have a list of tables in laravel with bootarps 5. For that, I have fetched ordering data from laravel and want to add pagination
*

```
{
"success": true,
"message": "",
"data": [
    {
        "id": 29,
        "code_database": 237751,
        "branch": "Kantor Pusat"
    }
],
"links": {
    "first": "http://ibn.tes/api/accurate/branch?page=1",
    "last": "http://ibn.tes/api/accurate/branch?page=1",
    "prev": null,
    "next": null
},
"meta": {
    "current_page": 1,
    "from": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "links": [
        {
            "url": null,
            "label": "&laquo; Previous",
            "active": false
        },
        {
            "url": "http://ibn.tes/api/accurate/branch?page=1",
            "label": "1",
            "active": true
        },
        {
            "url": null,
            "label": "Next &raquo;",
            "active": false
        }
    ],
    "path": "http://ibn.tes/api/accurate/branch",
    "per_page": 100,
    "to": 1,
    "total": 1
}
```

}

Comment: which table you are using ? is it jquery datatable ?

Comment: What exactly is your problem?